# Jest test fails when environment is configured with webpack-hot-middleware

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, jestjs, webpack-hot-middleware

So I'm running a very basic Jest test to test if one of my routes returns a 200.

```
import request from 'supertest';
import app from './../app';

describe('GET /', () => {
  it('should render properly', async () => {
    await request(app).get('/api/testing').expect(200);
  });
});
```

This was working perfectly then I configured webpack-hot-middleware and it seems to break at line 2 where I import app.

```
TypeError: setInterval(...).unref is not a function

  at createEventStream (node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/middleware.js:50:17)
  at webpackHotMiddleware (node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/middleware.js:12:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (server/app.js:62:73)
  at Object.<anonymous> (server/test/routes.test.js:2:38)
```

If I remove the following code from my app.js the tests all run fine.

```
  app.use(middleware);
  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.write(middleware.fileSystem.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html')));
    res.end();
  });
```

Has anyone configured Jest for webpack-hot-middleware? I'm kind of lost because I feel like I've tried everything.

Answer (score 8):

You must set [testEnvironment](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#testenvironment-string) Jest config option to `node`. `unref()` exists in Node.js only.

Comment: e.g., add "jest": { "testEnvironment": "node" } to package.json root level.

Comment: Thanks @jws ! For me I had to put `testEnvironment: 'node'` in my jest.config.ts

Answer (score 1):

By adding a @jest-environment docblock at the top of the file, you can specify another environment to be used for all tests in that file, refer to [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string)

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import request from 'supertest';
import app from './../app';

describe('GET /', () => {
  it('should render properly', async () => {
    await request(app).get('/api/testing').expect(200);
  });
});
```